# C# code php equivalent md5 hash

Tags: c#, php

I have this C# code:

```
 public static string Encript(string strData)
{
    string hashValue = HashData(strData);
    string hexHashData = ConvertStringToHex(hashValue);
    return hexHashData;
}

public static string HashData(string textToBeEncripted)
{
    //Convert the string to a byte array
    Byte[] byteDataToHash = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToBeEncripted);

    //Compute the MD5 hash algorithm
    Byte[] byteHashValue = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(byteDataToHash);

    return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteHashValue);
}


public static string ConvertStringToHex(string asciiString)
{
    string hex = "";
    foreach (char c in asciiString)
    {
        int tmp = c;
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint) System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Here you can see an [online version](http://rextester.com/YKHR97166).As you can see for the string "test" I get the output "5c82e9e41c7599f790ef1d774b7e6bf"
And this is what I tried on php side

```
$a = "test";
$a = mb_convert_encoding($a, "UTF-16LE");
$a = md5($a);
echo $a;
```

But the value of the php code is "c8059e2ec7419f590e79d7f1b774bfe6".Why is not working?

Edit:Looks like the C# code is incorrect and needs to be replaced

Comment: "5c82e9e41c7599f790ef1d774b7e6bf" is not in md5 try here http://md5.gromweb.com/

Comment: 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 is the correct MD5 hash for "test", lose the encoding crap.

Comment: You really should not be using `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteHashValue)`. The hash value is binary data which may contain sequences that are not valid UTF. If you need to return it as a string, it should be in Base64 encoding or a hex encoding directly from the array of bytes.

Comment: Well the string "5c82e9e41c7599f790ef1d774b7e6bf" is only 31 characters long but MD5 according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 should be 32 characters.I don't know C# code only php.And I have to make an php equivalent that will give me the same outpu.#Edit saw the comments to late I will try base64 encoding

Comment: If the C# code is generating an incorrect MD5 hash then it's that that needs fixing rather than attempting to get PHP to generate the same faulty value, surely?

Comment: Ofcourse. If the C# code is incorrect that will have to be fixed. I thought the C# code is correct as is coming from a "trusted" source.

Comment: @FoxAlex The MD5 hash calculation produces the correct results, if you use it correctly. But if you use the Unicode (ie UTF16) encoding, your bytevector is `[116, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0]` which is different from `[116, 101, 115, 116]` and thus produces a different hash value. Furthermore it would be better to generate the final hashstring directry from the bytearray resulting from the hashingfunction.

Comment: @derpischer And instead of Unicode what should be used?

Answer (score 5):

The correct MD5 hash for 'test' is '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' in PHP.

I tested it with this code in C#

```
   public static string CreateMD5(string input)
    {
        // Use input string to calculate MD5 hash
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

It will generate the same hash as PHP will, without the 'convert encoding' method you are using.

Comment: That's the correct value if you use ASCII encoding. But the OP is using Unicode encoding, which gives a different different `inputBytes` value.

Comment: That's not what he asks, he was trying to modify the PHP code, because the C# code gave the wrong results. Atleast, that's what i make out of his comments.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit unclear if he's trying to make the PHP program match the C#, or make the C# match the PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I believe converting the encoding is what is giving you a different answer, try it without

```
$a = mb_convert_encoding($a, "UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: I have already tried that before asking the question the value is "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6".Is not matching the C# value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are converting the result incorrectly in your C# code. If you put a breakpoint in the code after you call `ComputeHash`, and examine the value of `byteHashValue`, you'll see that it's `c8059e2e...`.

Or, just add this code to your `ComputeHash` method:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(byteHashValue));
```

I would suggest rewriting your code to be:

```
    public static string Encript(string strData)
    {
        string hashValue = HashData(strData);
        return hashValue;
    }

    public static string HashData(string textToBeEncripted)
    {
        //Convert the string to a byte array
        Byte[] byteDataToHash = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToBeEncripted);

        //Compute the MD5 hash algorithm
        Byte[] byteHashValue = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(byteDataToHash);

        return BitConverter.ToString(byteHashValue).Replace("-", "");
    }
```

Oh, and a side note: the word is "Encrypt," not "Encript."

Comment: Downvoter: It's customary to provide a reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is not the encoding, but your conversion to string on the C# side. As long as you use the same encoding everywhere, it should work as expected. But note, that most of the online hashers use `ASCII` encoding, whereas you use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` which is UTF-16, thus the results will differ from the online encoders.

The code below will give the same result as your PHP snippet (ie `c8059e2ec7419f590e79d7f1b774bfe6`)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = "test";
    string en = HashData(a);
    Console.WriteLine(en);
}

public static string HashData(string textToBeEncripted)
{
    Byte[] byteDataToHash = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToBeEncripted);
    Byte[] byteHashValue = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(byteDataToHash);
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (var b in byteHashValue)
        s.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    return s.ToString();
```

}

If you use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` instead, you will get `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` as suggested in other answers. But then you'll have to use ASCII encoding in your PHP code as well.

This is because with UTF16 every character is represented by two bytes, and not only by one. Thus the `byteDataToHash` will have twice the size (`[116, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0]` vs `[116, 101, 115, 116]` in your case). And a different bytevector of course leads to a different hashvalue. But as said above, as long as all included components use the same encoding, it does not really matter which one you use.